# Параметры фильтра post при переходе на 2 страницу

Tags: php, post, фильтры, netcat

На netcat реализован фильтр, передача параметров через POST; возникает проблема при переходе на 2 и далее страницы (в netcat это добавление к url "?curPos=20" )- параметры фильтрации не передаются на следующую страницу и сбрасываются. Как можно передать параметры фильтра на следующую страницу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Варианта:

1) Правильный вариант: Никак. Фильтр должен быть в Get параметрах

2) Неправильный вариант: Делать извращение типа пагинации состоящей из форм, в которых будут фильтры .

Comment: Куда ни наткнусь, везде пугают тем, что GET небезопасен, это правда?

Comment: А сеошника, тем временем, пугает "жуткая ссылка" при фильтрации по нескольким параметрам

Comment: @KBriezy сеошник говорит ерунду по нескольким причинам: 1) Прямых ссылок на каждый из фильтров не будет 2) Фильтры надо ставить запрещенными к индексации для роботов 3) Если параметры будут в post то нельзя будет передать ссылку с фильтром другому человеку - это минус к поведенческим факторам 4) Посмотрите крупные интернет магазины - там все глупые, а ваш сеошник умный?

Comment: @KBriezy по поводу безопасности, POST на столько же небезопасный как и GET.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! :)